# Xcode 4: How Do I Add Preprocessor Macros. Maddening

Tags: xcode4

So,

In Xcode 3 adding a preprocessor macro was easy. Xcode 4 not so. Can someone please provide me with the secret handshake?

Thanks, 
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to resort to editing the project file in a text editor. Sigh ...

Answer (score 2):

The build setting to set a preprocessor macro didn't change in Xcode 4. Use the Preprocessor Macros build setting, which is in the Preprocessing build settings collection.

What did change in Xcode 4 is where the build settings are located. Read the following to find the build settings in Xcode 4:

[Xcode 4: Accessing Build Settings](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/)

Comment: thanks for this. The problem is (was) there was no preprocessor collection present. My project was originally created in the dark ages of Xcode 3 when we had no need for the macro. My solution? I had to edit the project file in TextMate to make the collection appear in the build settings. Xcode 4 FTW ... Not.

Comment: It's strange that your Xcode 3 project didn't have a Preprocessing collection. The Preprocessing collection dates back to at least Xcode 2.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this in a .h file?

```
#define BLANK_IF_NIL(__STRING) (__STRING ? __STRING : @"")
```

And in your .m file...

```
NSLog("My string: @%", BLANK_IF_NIL(myString));
```

Comment: So, in Xcode 3, in the build settings - not source code - it was possible to set one or more preprocessor macros. Xcode 4 is maddeningly opaque about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @dugla's answer:

Edit `project.pbx`(which can be found inside `YourProject.xcodeproj` by selecting show package contents in Finder). Search for:

```
 /* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
```

and in here you want to add:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (
    "DEBUG=1",
    "$(inherited)",
);
```

so you end up with something like:

```
/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
    E4B69B4E0A3A1720003C02F2 /* Debug */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        baseConfigurationReference = E4EB6923138AFD0F00A09F29 /* Project.xcconfig */;
        buildSettings = {
            ARCHS = "$(NATIVE_ARCH)";
            CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = "$(SRCROOT)/bin/";
            COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
            DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING = YES;
            GCC_AUTO_VECTORIZATION = YES;
            GCC_ENABLE_SSE3_EXTENSIONS = YES;
            GCC_ENABLE_SUPPLEMENTAL_SSE3_INSTRUCTIONS = YES;
            GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO;
            GCC_MODEL_TUNING = G5;
            GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO;
            GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS = NO;
            GCC_WARN_ABOUT_INVALID_OFFSETOF_MACRO = NO;
            GCC_WARN_ALLOW_INCOMPLETE_PROTOCOL = NO;
            GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = NO;
            GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VALUE = NO;
            GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE = NO;
            OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS = (
                "-D__MACOSX_CORE__",
                "-lpthread",
            );
            GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (
                "DEBUG=1",
                "$(inherited)",
            );
        };
        name = Debug;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing the $(inherited) bit and your sample jogged my memory.